# Not able to change display picture from the default one

Tags: support

I have tried several times but I am just not able to change my display picture from the default `Identicon`. I don't receive any error, after I select my display picture and click on `Add picture` the change is reflected on that page but when I go back to my profile tab, it reverts back to the default `Identicon`.

Comment: Did you click the "Save Changes" button at the very bottom of the settings page?

Comment: Oh wow. I missed it completely but even if I had seen it I would've thought that it's for saving the other profile details. Anyway, please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly save the changes: You can click either the <kbd>Save changes just for this community</kbd> button or the <kbd>Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities</kbd> at the very bottom of the settings page.